# Use socket server connection at different code files with python

Tags: python, sockets

I created a socket server like this in python:

```
import socket             

s = socket.socket()         
print ("Socket successfully created")
  
port = 9998              
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), port))         
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port)) 
  
s.listen(5)     
print ("socket is listening")            
logging.info("Connection established")
  
# a forever loop until we interrupt it or 
# an error occurs 
while True: 
  
    # Establish connection with client. 
    c, addr = s.accept()     
    print ('Got connection from', addr )
  
    # send a thank you message to the client. 

    c.send('Thank you for connecting...'.encode()) 
    print(c.recv(1024)) 
  
    # Close the connection with the client 
    c.close()
```

I need to use server connection from other classes and files in python.So I need to send messages to clients from other python files using this server connection?

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Make a function, then import it in other files...

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: Do you know how to make functions? Do you know how to import classes and functions from one file into another?

Comment: Yes I know. I dont know how to use in socket code

Comment: yes please  MattDMo ,explain,  we are novices and dont know anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the client socket in some other function, you have to call that function with the connection as parameter:

```
import socket
from some_module import some_function

PORT = 9998

def main():
    server_socket = socket.socket()

    # bind to any address
    server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', PORT))
    print(f"socket binded to {PORT}")

    server_socket.listen(5)
    print("socket is listening")
  
    # a forever loop until we interrupt it or 
    # an error occurs 
    while True: 
        # Establish connection with client. 
        client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()     
        print(f"Got connection from {addr}")
        # don't use low-level functions send or recv.
        connection = client_socket.makefile('rw', encoding="utf8")

        # send a thank you message to the client. 
        connection.write('Thank you for connecting...\n') 
        print(connection.readline()) 
        some_function(connection)
        client_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```